# Docker: How to copy all png files in a docker to host?

Tags: docker

Is there a way to copy all files with a given extension to host machine in docker? Something like

`docker cp container_name:path/to/file/in/docker/*.png path/on/host`

Comment: Do you have a shell in the container, like `/bin/sh` with the `tar` command available?

Comment: Have you checked what has been discussed at this open issue: [Proposal: support wildcards and destination names in `docker cp` #7710](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/7710)? [@thaJeztah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811501/thajeztah) mentions: *"It's still open, I don't think someone looked into this, but contributions welcome. Implementation may be non-trivial though (i.e.; correctly implementing wildcard matching has proven to be tricky)"*

Comment: Do you need to do copy? Maybe just attach volume.

Comment: @Jaro...I need to clear the copied out file after some interval.Storing them in volume would require the clearing scripts to know the stored location on host machine

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a tar command and use the stdout pipe from an exec command to transfer this. You would need a shell and tar inside the container, and tar on the host, for this to work:

```
docker exec container_name tar -cC /path/to/file/in/docker "*.png" \
  | tar -xC path/on/host
```